# PHP cannot redeclare function

Tags: php

I am making a contact form for my site, and it uses a database to store messages sent. I have written a function which adds the message, and the users email, however when I call it in `addcontactmessage.php` it tells me that I cannot redeclare the function.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare add_message() (previously declared in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\Portfolio -- Website\asset\functions.php:3) in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\Portfolio -- Website\asset\functions.php on line 5

init.php:

```
<?php
require'connect.php';
require'functions.php';
?>
```

addcontactmessage.php:

```
<?php

include'asset/init.php';

    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    add_message($message, $email);

    header('Location: index.php'); 
?>
```

functions.php:

```
<?php
    include 'init.php';
    function add_message ($message, $email) {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `contactmessage`(`message`, `email`) VALUES ('$message,'$email')");
    }
?>
```

Comment: `functions.php` includes `init.php` and `init.php` includes `functions.php`. That's an infinite loop.

Comment: Go with barmar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29807608/797495

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are including `init.php` twice. Once in addcontactmessage.php and again in functions.php.

I'd recommend removing the include 'init.php'; line from your functions.php page.

Or

You can use php's built in functions `require_once` and `include_once` to avoid loading the same file more than once.

---

An example

init.php:

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php';
require_once('functions.php');
?>
```

addcontactmessage.php:

```
<?php

include_once('asset/init.php');

    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    add_message($message, $email);

    header('Location: index.php'); 
?>
```

functions.php:

```
<?php
    include_once('init.php');
    function add_message ($message, $email) {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `contactmessage`(`message`, `email`) VALUES ('$message,'$email')");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `require_once` and `include_once` to prevent loading the same include file twice.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, was just about to suggest it. `init.php` is being included back inside of `functions.php`. Removing it from `functions.php` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You're including `init.php` twice.

Remove `include 'asset/init.php`  from

`addcontactmessage.php` or `functions.php`, which one comes **last**.